# Como redirecionar para uma página caso url não contenha uma palavra?

Tags: jquery

Eu gostaria que caso não existisse uma string no url, ele redirecionasse para uma página. Isto foi o que eu tentei

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(!window.location.href.indexOf("www") > -1) {
        var link = window.location.href;
        var ver = link.substr(link.indexOf("index.php"));
        window.location.href="https://www.famalicaocanal.pt/"+ver;
    }
});
```

Com o código acima ele funciona mas ele continua sempre a dar refresh à página mesmo se existir `www` no url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sinal de exclamação `!` serve para transformar uma condição falsa em verdadeira e vice-versa.

Para comparar com `-1`, você **deve** remover essa `!` do início.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("www") < 0) {
        var link = window.location.href;
        var ver = link.substr(link.indexOf("index.php"));
        window.location.href="https://www.famalicaocanal.pt/"+ver;
    }
});
```

Da forma que está, ele está transformando `window.location.href.indexOf("www")` em 0 ou 1 (falso ou verdadeiro respectivamente) e sempre 0 e 1 será maior que -1, tornando sua condição verdadeira sempre.

Comment: Resultou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar esta forma também:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if(location.href.indexOf("www") != -1) {
      var link = location.href;
      var ver = link.substr(link.indexOf("index.php"));
      location.href="https://www.famalicaocanal.pt/"+ver;
   }
});
```

`window.location.href` e `location.href` são a mesma coisa. Já o `indexOf` pode retornar dois tipos de valores:

- **-1**, quando não encontra ocorrências e
- **0** ou **números positivos**, quando há ocorrências (dependendo da posição da *string*).

> Outra observação é não usar a palavra `link` para dar nome a objetos
>   (no seu caso, uma variável). O JavaScript **[possui uma lista](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)** de
>   palavras reservadas e `link` está entre elas. Embora possa funcionar
>   como uma variável no seu código, a recomendação é não usar palavras
>   reservadas para esse propósito.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta! Irei futuramente não usar a palavra link e afins para denominar variáveis! +1